# Python: how to read .csv file in an efficient way?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have to read some `.csv` files and do some operations. In particular I have to read `.csv` where the data is stored in different columns. In particular the data has the following format:

```
myfile_0.csv

Time InfD  Com ComN
  0   3     4   0
  1   2     5   1
```

The file contains many entries and I have to do that for different `parameters` an the process is really slow. In the following the task that I have to accomplish

```
for i in parameters:
    f = folder+'myfile_%d.csv'%i
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    D  = df.InfD / V
    C =  (df.Com/df.ComN)  
    size = TC - len(C)
    if len(C) < TC:
        CC = np.lib.pad(C, (0,size), 'constant', constant_values=(1))
        DD = np.lib.pad(D, (0,size), 'constant', constant_values=(0))
        cf = CC*(1-DD)
    else:
        C = C[0:TC]
        D = D[0:TC]
        cf = C*(1-D)
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient to solve the same problem.

Comment: You are going to have to read an entire file for every value in `parameters`. There is no way around that.

Comment: Try using [`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) to identify the bottleneck, then optimize those lines. Also, your question right now is a yes/no question and the answer is "yes, probably."

Comment: I was thinking to use `import csv` instead of pandas dataframe

Comment: it would be much easier to help you if you would provide bit more information. Do you want to slice your data frame if you have more than TC rows? why? why are you padding `CC` and `DD`? If you would provide a small input data set (5-7 rows), the algorithm how you want to process your data and an expected output. We could try to find a faster/more optimal way to do this.

Comment: Another question: you have one CSV file for each parameter - do you want to merge them after processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the python [csv library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```
import csv
with open('myfile_0.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        print ', '.join(row)

# output:
# Time, InfD, Com, ComN
# 0, 3, 4, 0
# 1, 2, 5, 1
```